# Mixed Mode Authentication in kentico 11

Tags: kentico

I want use Mixed mode authentication in my application.
I want Windows AD Authentication for intranet users and Forms authentication for internet users.
How can I configure this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/configuring-windows-ad-authentication/configuring-mixed-mode-authentication) for Mixed Mode Authentication.

Essentially you will:

- determine if you want to import AD roles or not (web.config key)
- Add an LDAP connection string to your web.config
- Modify the membership and roleManager elements under `congfiguration/system.web` section in your web.config to use the AD connection string and provider
- map the username field

It's not a hard setup really and much easier if you don't have users already in the Kentico system.  If the username already exists in Kentico, the user will NOT be imported into Kentico from AD.